# dynamic image rendering in vue from my json file

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, frontend

trying to load my image from my Db.json file....for my homepage its working since am trying to have a list of products ..but then in my product detail page i can get the image to be rendered...

this is my Home.vue...and my product Detail.vue...the image is in my db.json...

```
<template>
  <Header />
  <div class="d-flex flex-row gap-5 flex-wrap m-3">
    <div v-for="product in products" :key="product.id" class="">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          :src="require(`@/assets/images/${product.image}`)"
          class="card-img-top"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <router-link
            :to="'/product-detail/' + product.id"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            >view product</router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <Footer />
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./Header";
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: { Header, Footer },
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },

  async mounted() {
    let result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/products");
    console.log(result);
    this.products = result.data;
  },
};
</script>

then this is my product detail.vue..

<template>
  <Header />
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Product Description</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="container mb-5">
    <hr />

    <div class="card">
      <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-sm-5 border-right">
          <article class="gallery-wrap">
            <div class="img-big-wrap">
              <img :src="require(`../assets/images/${product.image}`)" />
            </div>
            <!-- slider-product.// -->

            <!-- slider-nav.// -->
          </article>
          <!-- gallery-wrap .end// -->
        </aside>
        <aside class="col-sm-7">
          <article class="card-body p-5">
            <h3 class="title mb-3">{{ product.name }}</h3>

            <p class="price-detail-wrap">
              <span class="price h3 text-warning">
                <span class="currency">US $</span
                ><span class="num">{{ product.price }}</span>
              </span>
            </p>
            <!-- price-detail-wrap .// -->
            <dl class="item-property">
              <dt>Description</dt>
              <dd>
                <p>
                  {{ product.description }}
                </p>
              </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Model#</dt>
              <dd>12345611</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Color</dt>
              <dd>Black and white</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->
            <dl class="param param-feature">
              <dt>Delivery</dt>
              <dd>Russia, USA, and Europe</dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- item-property-hor .// -->

            <hr />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-5">
                <dl class="param param-inline">
                  <dt>Quantity:</dt>
                  <dd>
                    <select
                      class="form-control form-control-sm"
                      style="width: 70px"
                    >
                      <option>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                    </select>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- item-property .// -->
              </div>
              <!-- col.// -->
              <div class="col-sm-7">
                <dl class="param param-inline">
                  <dt>Size:</dt>
                  <dd>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">SM</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">MD</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input
                        class="form-check-input"
                        type="radio"
                        name="inlineRadioOptions"
                        id="inlineRadio2"
                        value="option2"
                      />
                      <span class="form-check-label">XXL</span>
                    </label>
                  </dd>
                </dl>
                <!-- item-property .// -->
              </div>
              <!-- col.// -->
            </div>
            <!-- row.// -->
            <hr />

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary text-uppercase">
              <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to cart
            </a>
          </article>
          <!-- card-body.// -->
        </aside>
        <!-- col.// -->
      </div>
      <!-- row.// -->
    </div>
    <!-- card.// -->
  </div>
  <!--container.//-->
  <Footer />
</template>
<script>
import Header from "./Header";
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";
export default {
  name: "ProductDetail",
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      product: {},
    };
  },

  async mounted() {
    let result = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:3000/products/" + this.$route.params.id
    );
    console.log(result);
    this.product = result.data;
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
/* Import Font Dancing Script */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
.title {
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  padding-top: 15px;
  left: 45%;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
</style>


db.json...

"products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "shirt",
      "price": "40",
      "description": "Product shirt",
      "image": "f2.jpg",
      "reviews": [
        { " id": 1, " comment": "Good product" },
        { "id": 2, "comment": "Excellent product" },
        { " id": 3, "comment": "Average product" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "shirt",
      "price": "40",
      "description": "Product shirt",
      "image": "f1.jpg",
      "reviews": [
        { " id": 1, " comment": "Good product" },
        { "id": 2, "comment": "Excellent product" },
        { " id": 3, "comment": "Average product" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

i need the image to be rendered  for my productDetail......thats where the problem is ...only for my productDetail page...for the home page its being rendered

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're product detail is trying to require a relative file path, which is `../assets/images/${product.image}`  which more than likely will try to find the file `/components/assets/images/${product.image}` which probably doesn't exist.  Use the syntax in your home page on the product detail page `` :src="require(`@/assets/images/${product.image}`)" ``

##### Home page image

```js
 <img
    :src="require(`@/assets/images/${product.image}`)"
    class="card-img-top"
    alt="..."
/>
```

##### Product detail

```js
<img :src="require(`../assets/images/${product.image}`)" />
```

Comment: Still getting the same error... for the product detail page.....